# Alternative for CrossLoop

Tags: windows, gratis, remote-access

Since 31-01-2014 [CrossLoop](http://www.crossloop.com/) isn't available anymore.

We used this a lot to give support to our technicians in the field.

For us it was a perfect, and free, solution to take over their laptop while they could still see what was being done so they might learn from it for the next time.

We are now looking for a, preferably free, alternative for CrossLoop.

The functionalities we are looking for are:

- Works with Windows 7 (and maybe Windows XP as well)
- completely take over remote laptop
- works via GPRS connection (laptop)
- dual view: the laptop owner has to be able to see what is being done
- free, or very low cost

[Google](http://www.google.nl/#q=crossloop+alternative) gives quite some alternatives, but most of them cost quite a lot, and I am also interested in personal experiences before we start using any of the tools extensively

Comment: completely take over remove laptop or remote laptop?

Comment: completely take over remote laptop :) .. sorry for the typo, and thanks for the edit :)

Comment: Take over what? I can kinda guess, but it would be nice to describe the software directly instead of naming it "Alternative-To some-unknown-software" :) Is it a remote-control solution like [TeamViewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamViewer) you're after?

Comment: Take over the whole laptop. The laptop has several programs on it which can be used by the technician, or by the remote supporters. We are looking for something like TeamViewer indeed, but for a low cost, and which can work over GPRS like CrossLooop could.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Fog Creek's Copilot](https://www.copilot.com/) for a while now for my remote support needs.

- It work with XP & Win 7
- It gives the remote user full mouse/keyboard control
- It doesn't blank the local screen like RDP does - the local user sees everything that's happening.

Caveats:
 - It's NOT free, but I don't think their pricing is bad.
 - I've never used it over a GPRS connection, so I'm not certain how it handles that. As long as there's a reasonable amount of bandwidth, it should be able to manage.
 - They do have free use on weekends, and $5 day passes, so setting up a test shouldn't break the bank.

Comment: thanks! i will give it a try and see if it works over our GPRS. Normal RDP doesn't work over GPRS (probably due to some security settings?)

Answer (score 1):

[Join.Me](https://www.join.me/) is a screen sharing software that works on Windows and Mac.  They have a paid-for edition, but I think the free version offers everything you asked for, except that I have not tried it over GPRS:

- The local user can consent to give the remote user full control
- The local user can see everything being done by the remote user